# questions with hidden but revealable hints and answers

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, code-request

I would like to create a notebook with questions that have attached hints and answers.  The hints and answers should be hidden, but the display should clearly indicate (e.g., with a button) that each can be expanded whenever the user desires.

As an example of a fairly ugly solution, one can put the question in a text cell followed by a text cell that provides a hint header, saying only "open for hint". The hint header cell would then be grouped with subsequent cells, we would make a cell group out of the bunch, and show the group opener.  The same thing could be done for the answer.  This is perhaps not horrible, but the group opener is a bit subtle, and changing style across the notebook would not be easy.  (Well ... perhaps tags?)  I'm looking for a better solution, especially one someone is already using with their students.

Comment: So, a notebook with spoiler space?

Comment: @J.M. Effectively, but I'd like a prettier solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `FlipView`:

```
FlipView[{
  Button@"Show hint",
  Column[{

    TextCell[
       "You can plot a function using:", "Notebook", "Text"
    ],
    ExpressionCell[
       Defer@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], "Notebook", "Input"
    ]
  }]
}]
```

[image]

---

alternatively, born from comments under Karsten's answer:

```
FlipView[{
   Button["Show hint"],
   Tooltip[
      Button["Show hint", Appearance -> "Pressed"],
      Column[{
         TextCell["You can plot a function using:", "Notebook", "Text"], 
         ExpressionCell[Defer@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], "Notebook", "Input"]
      }]
   ]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know about `FlipView`.  That's pretty good for the providing a hint.  `PopupView` is also worth toying with.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the advantage to using a `TextCell` rather than a string as the first expression? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A modification of the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118483/18476) provided by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) that uses an `AttachedCell` to give the hint:

```
Button[
 "Show hint",
 With[{box = EvaluationBox[]},
  SelectionMove[box, All, Expression];
  FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AttachCell[box,
    Cell[BoxData[GridBox[
       {
        {Cell["You can plot a function using:", "Text"]},
        {Cell[BoxData["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,1}]"], "Input"]},
        {ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]}
        }, GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}}]], 
     Background -> GrayLevel[0.75], "Print"], 
    {1, {Right, Top}}, {Left, Top}, 
    "ClosingActions" -> {"SelectionDeparture", "ParentChanged", "EvaluatorQuit"}]]]
```

[image: GIF]

---

In response to a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118428/questions-with-hidden-but-revealable-hints-and-answers/118503#comment320310_118503) by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba):

```
Tooltip[
 Button["Hint",
  With[{box = EvaluationBox[]}, SelectionMove[box, All, Expression];
   FrontEndExecute@
    FrontEnd`AttachCell[box, 
     Cell[BoxData[
       GridBox[{{Cell["You can plot a function using:", 
           "Text"]}, {Cell[BoxData["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,1}]"], 
           "Input"]}, {ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]}}, 
        GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}}]], 
      Background -> GrayLevel[0.75], 
      "Print"], {1, {Right, Top}}, {Left, Top}, 
     "ClosingActions" -> {"SelectionDeparture", "ParentChanged", 
       "EvaluatorQuit"}]]],
 "Click this button if you need a hint"]
```

Comment: I think this will solve a problem that came up in one of my applications. Thank you for this!

Comment: @J.M. and Karsten no need for artillery: `Tooltip["Show hint", 
 RawBoxes@BoxData[
   GridBox[{{Cell["You can plot a function using:", "Text"]}, {Cell[
       BoxData["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,1}]"], "Notebook", 
       "Input"]}, {ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]}}, 
    GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}}]],
 TooltipDelay -> 1]`

Comment: @Kuba, but what I had in mind was something that would only show up upon clicking; `Tooltip[]`s show up on mere mouseovers.

Comment: @J.M. challenge accepted: `FlipView[{"Show hint",
  Tooltip["Show hint", 
   RawBoxes@
    BoxData[GridBox[{{Cell["You can plot a function using:", 
         "Text"]}, {Cell[BoxData["Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,1}]"], "Notebook", 
         "Input"]}, {ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]]}}, 
      GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}}]]]
  }]`

Comment: @Kuba This is as peaceful as the color swatches. My last edit demonstrates how I'd use `Tooltip` in this context.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your comment about color swatches :) p.s. Don't get me wrong with my Tooltip comment +1ed for usage of AttachCell which I find very useful.

Comment: @Kuba My code is based on a template I distilled from the structure of color swatches (ColorDirectiveSwatches). I thought you might be aware that these use `AttachCell` and from that perspective this answer is quite idiomatic.

Comment: @Karsten7. Your assumption was right, I'm just trying to lower my coffee consumption lately and this is what happens...

Answer (score 1):

```
TabView[{"Question" -> "What is a guppy?",
  "Hint" -> "Think about fish", 
  "Answer" -> 
   InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Enter your answer"]}]
```

or

```
MenuView[{"Question" -> "What is a guppy?",
  "Hint" -> "Think about fish", 
  "Answer" -> 
   InputField["", String, FieldHint -> "Enter your answer"]}]
```

Comment: I can definitely see situations where `TabView` would work, but I need the answer to include `Input` cells.